# How to programmatically pair a bluetooth device on Symbian using PyS60?

Tags: python, bluetooth, symbian, pys60

Is there a way to pair up two BT devices using PyS60? Perhaps there is a system API which prompts PIN and communicate with other device so it will appear as Paired device then. Unfortunately can't find this in PyS60 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Bluetooth examples for the "Mobile Python" book: http://www.mobilenin.com/mobilepythonbook/examples.html

Comment: Thanks, I studied these examples first.